# I there an open source XML viewer for Windows that can show data in grid form

Tags: xml

Excel can read raw XML and turn it into a a viewable table w/o a schema. I'm looking for a freeware/Open Source alternative for a situation whereby I don't have access to Excel. I don't need to edit, just view. Needs to be Windows-based.

Comment: Have you tried OpenOffice Calc? That's the most popular open-source Excel clone. Not sure if it can import XML, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple drag the XML file to your browser. I often open my XML files in Chrome and IE, because browsers display the XML files in easy for viewing XML structure way.

As you can ask to view files in windows, you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: Again, this is a web [solution](http://daigo.org/2010/08/simple-xml-to-html-table-using-jquery/) . This is a simple way to convert your XML to HTML table. Yes, you need some development but I doubt you will face soom problems as  the example is good. Although, it may a look slow and boring, you can prepare a HTML file as template and in variable there to copy/paste the XML data. I can do this for you, if you did not manage to create this template using the example on your own.

Comment: Opening in a browser doesn't render it table/spreadsheet like. I'm looking for an app that would allow me browse the XML data in a columnar fashion...